# pandas aggregation and grouping: group multiple columns, sort, pad and store array

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am attempting a to create a tensor from a dataframe, which contains regions of sequential data.

The attempts I have come up with utilize groupby/aggregate similar to the `df.groupby(groupcol)[aggcol].agg(list)` type of command, which easily gets a list of a column (aggcol) based on grouping a separate column  (groupcol)

Here is an example of two input dataframes (features and their metadata), and the resulting dataframe (annotated features by metadata and position) which is to be processed:

[image]

I am working on grouping these features into a list for each region:

[image]

But this needs to be padded to a certain length for each region (for example, by adding rows to each region level in the annotated features dataframe).

In other words, the resulting dataframe after grouping by region would be:

[image]

Such that I can return an array of the values within this dataframe in this format:

```
array([[[2.965e+03, 4.800e-01],
    [4.894e+03, 8.700e-01],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00]],

   [[7.920e+02, 1.700e-01],
    [3.029e+03, 8.100e-01],
    [4.852e+03, 7.400e-01],
    [9.548e+03, 6.000e-01],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00]],

   [[2.469e+03, 3.600e-01],
    [7.144e+03, 1.600e-01],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00]],

   [[5.783e+03, 7.000e-01],
    [7.068e+03, 6.000e-01],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00]],

   [[2.965e+03, 9.800e-01],
    [4.894e+03, 8.900e-01],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00]],

   [[7.920e+02, 8.600e-01],
    [3.029e+03, 8.600e-01],
    [4.852e+03, 6.900e-01],
    [9.548e+03, 5.900e-01],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00]],

   [[2.469e+03, 6.700e-01],
    [7.144e+03, 1.300e-01],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00]],

   [[5.783e+03, 8.400e-01],
    [7.068e+03, 9.900e-01],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00]],

   [[2.965e+03, 8.000e-02],
    [4.894e+03, 5.700e-01],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00]],

   [[7.920e+02, 4.000e-01],
    [3.029e+03, 1.100e-01],
    [4.852e+03, 8.000e-01],
    [9.548e+03, 3.400e-01],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00]],

   [[2.469e+03, 1.800e-01],
    [7.144e+03, 6.300e-01],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00]],

   [[5.783e+03, 4.700e-01],
    [7.068e+03, 3.200e-01],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
    [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00]]])
```

Here is the code for generating the input tables:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# DataFrame of Features in each document
num_features = 10
num_docs = 3
def calc_feats(): 
    return np.random.randint(0, 100, num_features)/100
d = {'document_'+str(i): calc_feats() for i in range(0, num_docs)}
# Unique feature index
d['feat_index'] = np.arange(0, num_features)
docs = pd.DataFrame(d)\
                .set_index('feat_index')

# DataFrame for metadata about features
regions_of_doc = ['mid', 'end', 'start', 'intro', 'title']
feature_regions = [np.random.choice(regions_of_doc) for i in range(0, num_features)]
feature_positions = np.random.randint(0, 10000, num_features)
feature_meta_info = pd.DataFrame({'feat_index': d['feat_index'],
                                'region': feature_regions,
                                'position_in_region': feature_positions,
                                'other_uninteresting_info': np.random.randint(0, 10000, num_times)})\
                    .set_index('feat_index')


# Join the two dataframes and set a multi-index to annotate the documents
combined_df = docs.join(feature_meta_info.drop('other_uninteresting_info', axis = 1))\
                    .reset_index()\
                    .set_index(['region', 'feat_index', 'position_in_region'])\
                    .sort_index(level = ['region', 'position_in_region'])

# add position features to each feature
pos = combined_df.index.get_level_values('position_in_region')
combined_df = combined_df.apply(lambda x: list(zip(pos, x)))

# display(multi_table([docs, feature_meta_info, ]))
display(HTML('<table><tr style="background-color:white;">' + \
             '<td>' + docs._repr_html_() + '</td>' + \
             '<td><img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Plus_symbol.svg", width = "50", height = "50"></td>' + \
             '<td>' + feature_meta_info._repr_html_() + '</td>' + \
             '<td><img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/Arrow_east.svg/800px-Arrow_east.svg.png", width = "50", height = "10"></td>' + \
             '<td>' + combined_df._repr_html_() + '</td>' + \
             '</tr></table>'))
```

Comment: Could you add an expected output in the form of a dataframe, so we can visually see what you are trying to do

Comment: @ Efran - That is what I put in the picture.  However, of course if I was capable of producing it *completely* I wouldn't need to ask the question. Since I was not capable of getting *exactly* what I wanted, I put something exceedingly close in the picture.  The only difference I I need is that each value is normalized to a certain length, and sorted by one axis (position axis), and the position axis is normed between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Erfan The code should be complete to generate what I am looking for - if it didn't provide the error.

Comment: I think what he means can you manually (ie type each row  of the output table in your post) create what the output table should look like. Its hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

After writing several minimal, complete, and verifiable examples and analogies on this I have some code that works.  It may not be performant (about to check that), but this is a way to do it with tons of `stack()` `sort_index()` and `groupby()` functions:

```
# stack documents into series 
# and then and order the index by document first, then region and position
featvals = combined_df.stack()
featvals.index.set_names(['region','feat_index','position_in_region', 'document'], inplace = True)
featvals = featvals.reorder_levels(order = ['document', 'region', 'position_in_region', 'feat_index'])\
                       .sort_index(level = ['document', 'region', 'position_in_region'])

display(featvals.to_frame())

# Group into lists by each document and region for each feature tuple
feat_by_region = featvals.groupby(level = ['document', 'region']).agg(list)

display(feat_by_region.to_frame())

def pad_lists(list_of_arrays, max_seq_len, null_value):
    arr = np.array([list(i) + [null_value] * (max_seq_len - len(i)) for i in list_of_arrays])
    return  arr

# Solution:
# Numpy array by getting the lists by `.values` and pad these arrays to a standardized length
feat_by_region_array = pad_lists(feat_by_region.values, max_seq_len = 7, null_value = (0,0))



# dataframe to view the feature array
feat_by_region = pd.DataFrame([tuple(i) for i in feat_by_region_array[..., :]], index = feat_by_region.index)
feat_by_region.columns.name = 'position_index'
display(feat_by_region)

# doesn't condense to properly formatted array (- because of tuples?)
display(np.array(feat_by_region.values).shape)
```

**output:**

stacking / ordering:

[image]

grouping to lists:

[image]

dataframe of values after padding:

[image]